# It is possible to mix options and arguments?

Tags: bash, getopts

Is it possible to mix options (with getopts) and arguments ($1....$10)?

Comment: Parsing cla in bash https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash

Answer (score 1):

`getopt` (singular) can handle options and arguments intermixed, as well as short `-s` and long `--long` options and `--` to end options processing.

See here how `file1` and `file2` are mixed with options and it separates them out:

```sh
$ args=(-ab opt file1 -c opt file2)
$ getopt -o ab:c: -- "${args[@]}"
 -a -b 'opt' -c 'opt' -- 'file1' 'file2'
```

Typical usage looks like:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

options=$(getopt -o ab:c: -l alpha,bravo:,charlie: -- "$@") || exit
eval set -- "$options"

# Option variables.
alpha=0
bravo=
charlie=

# Parse each option until we hit `--`, which signals the end of options.
# Don't actually do anything yet; just save their values and check for errors.
while [[ $1 != -- ]]; do
    case $1 in
        -a|--alpha)   alpha=1;    shift 1;;
        -b|--bravo)   bravo=$2;   shift 2;;
        -c|--charlie) charlie=$2; shift 2;;

        *) echo "bad option: $1" >&2; exit 1;;
    esac
done

# Discard `--`.
shift

# Here's where you'd actually execute the options.
echo "alpha:   $alpha"
echo "bravo:   $bravo"
echo "charlie: $charlie"

# File names are available as $1, $2, etc., or in the "$@" array.
for file in "$@"; do
    echo "file: $file"
done
```